# Simple Recursive function in javascipt jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        var i=100;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function blink(i) {
                if(i==0)
                    return;
                $(".target h1").fadeToggle(1000);
                i=i-1;
                blink(i);
            }
        });
        </script>
        <div class="target"><h1>I am blinking.</h1></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

when I use a for loop it works perfectly but no idea why its not running as expected in a recursive function.

Comment: 1. You have a syntax error in the code. Check your console. A function definition is `function() {}` not `function({}` 2. You never call `blink` for the first time, so it will never go into recursion. 3. This isn't even a task where recursion is suitable.

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error and other ones ,I have just started learning jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't run because you never call the function, you only create the function after the DOM is ready.

```js
const i = 3;
function blink(i) {
    if(i==0)
        return;
    $(".target h1").fadeToggle(1000);
    blink(i-1);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  blink(i)
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="target"><h1>I am blinking.</h1></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```